# The specified procedure could not be found. - Init_StringIO

Tags: ruby, stringio

Can someone tekl me what's going on here? This used to work for me but now I'm getting this error in both ruby 1.8.7 and ruby 1.9.3

```
require 'StringIO'
#LoadError: 127: The specified procedure could not be found.   - Init_StringIO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a problem with case:

```
require 'stringio'
str = StringIO.new
```

Comment: Yup, I guess that was it, how strange that it used to work for me the other way and now it doesn't :(